# IF Statement on VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF for displaying values from a related object. The related object is linked through a lookup field. Whenever the lookup field is null, the VF is populating the fields with weird information. For example, the date fields are showing today's date even though the lookup field has no record to pull this information from. I need these fields to be blank. I tried looking up how to fix this, but can't find anything. Any ideas?

```
<apex:page StandardController="Parent_Opportunity__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock title="Offers">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_1_Value__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_2_Value__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_3_Value__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Savings">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_1_Savings__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_2_Savings__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_3_Savings__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Timestamp">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.1__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.2__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.3__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.4__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.5__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="TAT">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.1__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.2__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.3__c }"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.4__c }"/><br></br><br></br><br></br>
        <apex:outputField value="{! Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.5__c }"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Someone actually gave a "-1" without even providing a comment on the case. It is these types of people that keep people from reaching out to communities for help. You don't see that type of treatment on other communities...

Comment: This is supposedly rare, but it does happen. I always leave a comment with a downvote unless a comment that already reflects my statement exists, in which case I upvote the comment. That said, I would imagine that the -1 came from the impression that this was just a "wall of code" question that we tend to downvote. I don't see a problem with this question as is, though. The code could have been trimmed down to just one section, for example, but it's clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the record doesn't exist in a relationship, the field takes on the Default Value for that field.

To solve this in markup, the if statement here would be something like:

```
{!IF(ISNULL(Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__c),null,Parent_Opportunity__c.ticket__r.Offer_1_Savings__c)}
```

To solve this in configuration, consider removing the Default Value for the field.

To solve this with Apex, you'd write an extension to clear the record if no Id exists on it, e.g.:

```
if(thisRecord.ticket__c == null) {
  thisRecord.ticket__r = new Ticket__c(); // Or whatever
}
```

Comment: I imagine this is a result of back-end magic on Salesforce's part to avoid null pointer exceptions when a relationship field is not populated. I wouldn't think that setting the embedded parent SObject reference to a blank object would work, but a quick test showed me that it does (well, at least for my test page with 1 `<apex:outputField>` involving a date field.)